# System of constraints in Sonic zk-SNARK protocol

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I am reading up on [Sonic: Zero Knowledge SNARKS from Linear - Sized Universal And Updateable Structured Reference Strings](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/099.pdf).

There is an example of representing $\ x^2 + y^2 = z $ constraint (page 7 of the paper):

[image]

Can somebody explain how the values for vectors `a,b,c,u,v,w,k` were obtained?

Comment: your screenshot is missing context. you need to define those vector variables you are asking about.

Comment: @kodlu, this is an example of Sonic constraints system application. There are other more famous constraint systems, for example R1CS. Example of R1CS applied to equation $\ x^3 + x +5 = 35 $ is shown in Vitalik Buterin's post (https://medium.com/@VitalikButerin/quadratic-arithmetic-programs-from-zero-to-hero-f6d558cea649). A similar explanation for Sonic case would be great